# Emulator command not recognized in command line

Tags: android, visual-studio, command-line, android-emulator

I am trying to use enulator command and list all of my emulator nevertheless i get infromation that command is not found. My avds are installed in visual studio.

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Info:

```
'emulator' is not recognized as an in external command
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add emulator ("$ANDROID_INSTALLATION/Android/Sdk/emulator") to your $PATH system variable. After updating your $PATH variable, you will need to restart the terminal session or open a new one and the command should be working.

Comment: What should the value of this environment variable be?

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran in Windows, it´s a system variable that holds the different addresses to directories of program or scripts that are used by the system users. Usually node, python and other technologies prompt you to add their installation directory to your PATH system variable.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set Environment path
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
or
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

Answer (score 3):

You need to set path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 0):

First go to android studio terminal and choose Command Prompt
[image]

then type cd in prompt and paste the path, changing the Pc_Name, to your user name `C:\Users\Pc_Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools`

[image]

Now just type the command followed by the emulator name, if the emulator name has spaces, replace it with `_` like this `emulator -avd API_34_droid-14`